# writing to json refactor code

Tags: c#, json

I am writing results i return from stored procedure into json. I did it but i am not sure if there is a simpler cleaner way other than what i have. Also how can i check that it really wrote to json?

```
var results = mySvc.GetInfo("Environment");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Id");
jsonWriter.WriteValue(results.Id);
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Head");
jsonWriter.WriteValue(results.Head);
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Value");
jsonWriter.WriteValue(results.Value);
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("GuidTwo");
jsonWriter.WriteValue(results.GuidTwo);
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("GuidOne");
jsonWriter.WriteValue(results.Guid1);
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
return results;
```

Comment: You can create DataContract object and use JSON serializer

Comment: To expand on @janisz suggestion : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) and you simply do this:

```
var results = mySvc.GetInfo("Environment");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
```

The inverse:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
```

Comment: this worked nicely - now if i want to get the info from json in a different method how could i extract from this?

Comment: Where did <Result> come from?

Comment: `Result` is the class that the data is deserialised into. In your case, it will be whatever type is returned by `mySvc.GetInfo()`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var results = mySvc.GetInfo("Environment");
var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObj = js.Serialize(results);
```

Comment: what namespace is serialization under?

Answer (score 2):

By using [ServiceStack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text) json serializer(it's faster than the json.net)

```
 Install-Package ServiceStack.Text
 using ServiceStack.Text;

 var json = results.ToJson();
```

Comment: and if i would like to extract information from Json - how will that look?

Comment: What is to consume the json?

Comment: @Masriyah Without using another class type to serialize to and from you can use  JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Dictionary<string, object>>(json); //not the best solution however with all the casting you'll need to do. - there must be a better way...